# Form Data to CSV File

Tags: html, c, forms

I have written some C code, which does not appear to be working correctly.  I have a POST form and I am looking to tokenize the output (based on the & limiting character) and write this to an output text file (with commas separating the data).

Any suggestions on this coding?

```
int main () 
{
    static const char Write2File[] = "csvoutput.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen ( Write2File, "w" );
    char line[128], str[128];
    char *p, *pch;

    // while stdin is not null
    while ( fgets (line) != NULL )
    {   
        // tokenize the string based on & character
        pch = strtok (line,"&");

        // writes the token to file
        fputs(pch,fp);

        // writes a comma to  file
        fputc(',',fp);

        // writes the token to file
        fputs(pch,fp);

        // takes a new line break
        fputc('\n',fp);
    }
    fclose ( fp );
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is.  What is the content of `line`? What appears in your csv file?

Comment: Sorry, the line
    while ( fgets (line) != NULL )
This is not compiling, I want to take whatever is in STDIN from the form, and use fgets to tokenize the string so that I can write it to the output file.

Comment: You need to put an inner strtok-loop for the tokenization of each line. Right know you only get the 1st token of each line and you double write it into your file (or so I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `fgets` with few params

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

You want to get POST?

```
char *slen;
char *post;
int len;

slen = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
if (slen && sscanf(slen, "%d", &len) == 1) {
    post = malloc((size_t)len + 1);
    /* check malloc */
    fgets(post, len + 1, stdin);
    /* strtok here */
    free(post);
}
```

Comment: David, I'm not 100% clear on your code - so do I need to add the strtok lines of the code into this?

Comment: Yes, `CONTENT_LENGTH` gives you the length of the string, post is the string to tokenize, also you have to deal with others chars, take a look to [url_decode](http://www.geekhideout.com/urlcode.shtml) or use some specific library, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is what you want

Answer (score 2):

No way that you managed to get that to compile.

This:

```
while( fgets(line) != NULL )
```

is quite wrong, `fgets()` needs more arguments, like so:

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL )
```

You can learn these things from the freely available [manual pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), just type "man fgets" into your favorite search engine.

Also, your program is going to need to have `#include <stdio.h>` for this to work.

Comment: You are right, I changed the line to
    while( fgets(line, 128, stdin) != NULL )
And it has compiled - but the page does not display anything.